# Scope of "this" element in jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to write a jQuery plugin to automate the filling of select boxes, but i am stumbling in the use of the this keyword in the "each" function. The code is as follows  :

```
(function($) { 
    $.fn.addOptionsTable2 = function() {        
    options = {
            values : text [...]
        };
        $.each(options, function(val,text) {
            this.append(
              $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
        );
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I believe the problem is the "this" reference.
How can i make this work and also what does the "this" refer to in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.each` sets `this` to the current object (for the loop).

Try this:

```
    var that = this;

    $.each(options, function(val,text) {
        that.append(
          $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
```

Comment: i was answering exactly the same, but i was too slow

Comment: I agree, the `that = this` solution is very prevalent in these situations.

Comment: I prefer `self`, but ... same thing. The important thing to understand is that `this` is *special* and set for each function-object invocation. (Exactly what it is set to can vary.)

Comment: The alternative is, of course, to use `bind` or `jQuery.proxy`.

Comment: @pst I tend to avoid avoid terms like `self` because they could be mistaken for a real keyword (particularly by those coming from other languages).

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin i actually searched for a "self" keyword in the API after seeing the answer

Comment: Just had a coworker insist 'that' was a keyword precisely because he's seen it in so many places.